# How to make all objects move as cursor

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt5, c++17

I have `QGroupBox` with `sliderclasses` (child class from QLabel) 
Picture:
[image: Picture]
I want to add `MouseEvent`: when I drag one `sliderclasses` - another classes will move.
Movement will be as mouse trajectory.
Like this: 
Picture:
[image: Picture]

sliderclass.hpp:

```
#ifndef SLIDERCLASS_HPP
#define SLIDERCLASS_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class sliderclass : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit sliderclass(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
private:
    QPoint m_dragPosition;
    bool firstCIsNotNull = true;
};

#endif // SLIDERCLASS_HPP
```

sliderclass.cpp:

```
#include "sliderclass.hpp"

sliderclass::sliderclass(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
}

void sliderclass::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if ((ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && firstCIsNotNull){
        auto tmp = this->parent()->children();
        for(auto obj : tmp) {
            auto cbox = static_cast<QLabel*>(obj);
            cbox->move(cbox->mapToParent(ev->pos() - m_dragPosition - cbox->geometry().topLeft()));
        }
    }
}

void sliderclass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            m_dragPosition = ev->pos();
            firstCIsNotNull = true;
    }
}

void sliderclass::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            firstCIsNotNull = false;
    }
}
```

BUT! This code doesn't work for all QLabels.
All QLabels moves not by trajectory - they all move to final pos of the first QLabel and
all QLabels are layered on top of each other.